# apps script getBody doesn't give full html contents

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, gmail-api

I get emails from a system that contains paragraphs and tables.

When I try to get full html format using `getBody` from email it gives me just CSS contents and not the whole html contents.
[image: This is 'inspect element' of email that doesn't work.]
[image: Just CSS with no HTML contents.]

However when I copy full email body and send it to myself in a new email then `getBody` function gives me accurately full body in html format including all tags and contents.
[image: This is 'inspect element' of email that works.]
[image: Correct Html data]

Kindly guide what I am missing here?

```
var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("INBOX/reports0");
var threads = label.getThreads();
var tempbody = threads[i].getMessages()[0].getBody();
```

Regards

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow please take this opportunity to take the [tour] and learn how to [ask], [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks), [mcve] and [Tag Info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info)

Comment: Done, Thanks you

Comment: As the logged output in the console is too large and it's being truncated you're not seeing the whole output in the neither of the cases, probably you're getting the entire HTML you just don't see it there. Use Stackdriver logs instead. I can't replicate your issue with the information you've provided, could you add .eml files from sample emails (without private information) where you can replicate this issue?

Comment: Andres, you are right. I was not seeing whole output. I used Google Doc to read the whole output and found where was the difference in two types of emails. Actually one email was showing <td> while other was showing <td class=...) for same components. Changing the regex according to this change solved the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the logged output in the console is too large and it's being truncated you're not seeing the whole output in neither of the cases, you're getting the entire HTML you just don't see it there. You can use [Stackdriver logging](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/logging#stackdriver_logging) instead to show the whole output.